# Android cannot resolve type ulong64

Tags: android, c++, c, cmake, android-ndk

**Objective**

To generate the hash of a image file. I am using [pHash](http://www.phash.org/docs/howto.html) library for this task. pHash library has below method used for generating the image hash.

```
int ph_dct_imagehash(const char* file,ulong64 &hash);
```

Datatype ulong64 is not present in android stdint.h. Due to which I am getting **"cannot resolve type ulong64"** error.

Please help how I can use ulong64 in c file in Android.

Can I use some third party library for this task?

Do we have any way around to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type is specific to pHash, and it is defined inside pHash.h by the following snippet:

```
#if defined( _MSC_VER) || defined(_BORLANDC_)
typedef unsigned _uint64 ulong64;
typedef signed _int64 long64;
#else
typedef unsigned long long ulong64;
typedef signed long long long64;
#endif
```

To use this type, just `#include <pHash.h>`.